# My jquery submit handler is not called in Chrome

Tags: jquery

My jquery submit handler is not called in Chrome. Here is the code:

```
<input
accesskey="s"    
class="button"    
id="issue-link-submit"
name="Link"
title="Press Alt+s to submit this form"
type="submit"
value="Link"
/> 

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#issue-link-submit').submit(function() {
alert('hi');
});
</script>
```

But it is working fine in IE and FF. 
Could you please help me on this?
Thanks in advance!

-Chintu

Comment: Do you get any error in the developer's tools console? Try adding return false in the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#issue-link-submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    alert('hi');
});
</script>
```

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to press the tick and mark as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As scripts execute before the page is necessarily parsed and rendered, you must wrap all jQuery code which depends on the DOM in a **document.ready** callback.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('#issue-link-submit').submit(function() {
       alert('hi');
       return false; //prevent default?
     });
   }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript code to this:

```
$("formId").submit(function() {
   alert('hi');
   return true;
});
```

Replace `#issue-link-submit` with your form id. If there is no form id, then add an id to the form.

You can not add `#issue-link-submit` selector to submit handler directly, because you are adding submit handler to the button. You need to add the submit handler to the form element.